useMutation issue with apollo composable and vue
Pretty new to vue/apollo and mutations and I'm wondering how can I call a mutation that the query mutation depends on the value from the input of the function.
I've been trying this but all I got back was
Error: Apollo client with id default not found. Use an app.runWithContext() or provideApolloClient() if you are outside of a component setup.

async function cancelExams(device: string, id, type) {
  const status = 'CANCELED'
  const data = {
    id,
    status,
  }
  if (type === 'VF') {
    data.fields = {
      update: [{ data: { status }, filter: { id } }],
    }
  }

  // Option 2
  const {
    mutate: updateStudyMutation,
    loading: statusUpdateLoading,
    onError: statusUpdateError,
    onDone: statusUpdateDone,
  } = useMutation(getInstanceMutation(type))

  await updateStudyMutation({ data })
}

